# google sheet query group by content of column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm pretty new to the query function and still testing to get the query work as I want it. In my google spreadsheet I have a table like this:

```
Playername    Mode   Points
PlayerA       1v1    500
PlayerA       2v2    540
PlayerA        -       
PlayerA
PlayerA       3v3    430
PlayerA       3v3s   540
PlayerB       1v1    700
PlayerB       2v2    800
PlayerB        -      

...
```

Because I continue to add new Players and want a nice overview and add calculations to it, I need a result like this:

```
Playername   1v1   2v2   3v3   3v3s
PlayerA      500   540   430   540
PlayerB      700   800   ...
```

I don't really know how to get the content (excluding the "-" and empty ones) of the "Mode" Column as new Columns in the query function. This is my function for now to get rid of the empty and "-" rows.

```
=QUERY(datarange;"select A, B, C where (B<>'-' and B<>'')";1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use both GROUP BY and PIVOT clauses of the SELECT statement:

```
=query(A28:C36, "select A, sum(C) where B<>'-' and B<>'' group by A pivot B", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: worked for me, thanks a lot! I only need to edit the last "," to a ";"

=query(A28:C36, "select A, sum(C) where B<>'-' and B<>'' group by A pivot B"; 1)